# PHPMyAdmin "#2006 - MySQL server has gone away" during login

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

First: I've searched all over Google and although this looks like an infamous error, none is actually my case and hence no fix is available.

OK so today I encountered this something weird: PHPMyAdmin suddenly refuses to log me in. Logging and checking show `#2006 - MySQL server has gone away`. Below is the list of fixes I've desperatedly tried:

- Switch between `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`, `tcp` and `socket`
- Set `max_allowed_packet` to a generous `256M` in `my.cnf`
- Set `wait_timeout` to a hefty `600`.
- Run `mysql_upgrade` from the `root` account
- Completely reinstall PHPMyAdmin to the latest version 4.5.2
- Swap between `mysql` and `mysqlnd` PHP extensions
- Completely remove PHP7, reinstall 5.6, and upgrade to 7 again (!)

What's strange is, normal `mysqli_*` functions work fine. [Adminer](https://www.adminer.org) works without a flaw as well, which leads me to a conclusion that this is most likely PHPMyAdmin's fault.

And this is my spec:

- CentOS 6.5
- MySQL 5.5.44
- PHPMyAdmin 4.5.2
- mysql/mysqlnd extension
- PHP 7.0 or 5.6

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

Change config `ssl` to `false` like so:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl'] = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally. The problem is with the "Force SSL" option. Disabling it brings PHPMyAdmin back alive and kicking.

Comment: Hi, can you be more specific please? What do you mean by "Force SSL" option. Both my `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl'] = false;` and `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl_verify'] = false;` . But I still keep getting the same error you are getting